# Assert in code - Asserting in try catch

Tags: c#

I am using assert in code to verify assumptions and throw give me nice messages, like this:

```
int IntegerDivide ( int dividend , int divisor )
{ 
    Debug.Assert ( divisor != 0 );
    return ( dividend / divisor ); 
}
```

(exemple from [Assertions in Managed Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttcc4x86.aspx)).

Now I am just wondering if I could use that to check for code that should not throw exceptions. Something like this could do:

```
try
{
    //code
}
catch (exceptionThatShouldntHappen ex)
{
   Debug.Assert(false,"This exception should never happen!")
}
```

Is that done? I mean, obviously it only makes sense for code that has its exceptions caught down the line, or it would break anyway. But that is the point, you imagine the calling code will catch a wide range of exceptions, but some just aren't meant to happen. You make sure that those exceptions always break, at lest in debug, no matter how the caller is catching them.

> I'll go for a more detailed example: suppose I have a data access
>   class. It can throw all sorts of exceptions.
>
> The calling code will therefore catch exceptions. Sometimes (or most times?), the calling code won't have information enough, or care, what exceptions are
>   possible. I mean, a FindRecord() that fails failed, no matter how. You catch
>   and return an error page or a message, or even fallback.
>
> But in the data access logic, some error should not happen (let's say file not found, if the file is presumed to be checked before). That's when this comes in. You assert, so that no matter how the upstream code is catching exceptions, it will break during debug - which is what assertions are for anyway.

Finally, if this practice makes sense, I'd like to know what is the best way to do it. Adding `try-catch` all over the place must have a big impact (for methods that have no try catch at first). `#if DEBUG` around the `try-catch` looks ugly as hell.

Comment: While different languages, they're fundamentally about the same problem. Core idea: just omit it -- if the exception is thrown, the test will automatically fail.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel The point is that `Debug.Assert` will cause the debugger to break on the assert fail (which handled exceptions usually *do not* break)

Comment: @Rob then execute the tests in debug mode.. am I missing something?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel What part of this post is related to tests? To me it appears the goal is to have the debugger immediately break while being debugged and presumably in development.

Comment: @Rob ah, fair enough. I was confused and interpreted it as a test

Comment: No, no testing involved. When you assert in code, there are two consequences: the assert code is ignored by the compiler (no impact on release code), and if in debug mode, the code breaks (just like an exception, but this one can't be caught - it breaks every time).

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to do the `try...catch`, any exceptions that are thrown will bubble up until someone handles them.

The `Debug.Assert` in the `catch` would just raise an exception only in debug mode. Most of the time the you can just let the debugger break on exceptions.

You should use Assertions for invariants, and just let other exceptions be raised until something needs to handle them.

In your case, I don't think there is anything you would want to handle the exception.

It could be better to have a specific `ArgumentException` replace the `Debug.Assert`, that way in release mode the exception is more useful, but in your example it's neither here nor there.

Comment: True, but the case in hand is exactly when you _don't_ want the calling code to catch that particular exceptions, because it's presumed to never happen... Sure, if the calling code is meticulous about what exceptions to catch, that would not be an issue.

Comment: But if it never happens, why bother detailing what should happen if it does? My response to "This will never happen" is always "OK, then I'll just crash hard" .Invariably people immediately responds with "No no, we can't do that" in which case you know it might sometimes happens and thus warrant a better handling. Also consider the law of big numbers. If you think "this will happen 1 in a 10000 times". If you have a million users, chances are 100 people are experiencing it.